# Identify matching strings in column and create new column with numbers for each string in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I have a tibble that looks somewhat like the following:

```
block  description
1      enroll
1      enroll
1      motivated
1      motivated
1      motivated
2      openemail
2      openemail
```

I would like to create a new column with a unique number corresponding to each unique value in the "description" column. There are many more unique values in the description column than are shown here. I am wondering if there is a way for R to identify which unique values match each other and then generate a new value for each one, so that the resulting tibble looks like this:

```
block  description  question
1      enroll       1
1      enroll       1 
1      motivated    2
1      motivated    2
1      motivated    2
2      openemail    3
2      openemail    3
```

I was planning on using mutate() to create the new column but am not sure what the input should be. Ideally, there is a way to do this without me typing in each unique value that could possibly be under "description".

EDIT: The combination of the below solutions that worked best for me is the following:

```
df$question <- as.integer(factor(df$description, levels = unique(df$description)))
```

Comment: is `block` relevant to your calculation for unique values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `as.integer(factor())` to get the desired result. Specifying the levels manually with `unique()` avoids the default sorting when `levels = NULL`, so that levels are in the order of appearance in the dataframe. See that I reordered some rows to make it clear that the first appearance of the level determines its index.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- read_table2(
"block  description
 1      enroll
 2      openemail
 1      enroll
 2      openemail
 1      motivated
 1      motivated
 1      motivated"
)
df %>%
  mutate(index = as.integer(factor(description, levels = unique(description))))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#>   block description index
#>   <int> <chr>       <int>
#> 1     1 enroll          1
#> 2     2 openemail       2
#> 3     1 enroll          1
#> 4     2 openemail       2
#> 5     1 motivated       3
#> 6     1 motivated       3
#> 7     1 motivated       3
```

Created on 2018-04-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: For the solution using mutate, I get two errors: 1) that object "." is not found and 2) that group_indices cannot be used on an object of class "character". Any idea how to address these?

Comment: Your solution starting with df$index does not assign numbers in the order in which they are originally shown in the df, but rather it assigns them in alphabetical order.

Comment: If you need them in the order of appearance the above should do the trick, avoiding the default sorting of factor values in `as.factor`. `group_indices` will not work as a solution if you need them not sorted, so I removed it. Though now redundant, I can only suggest that you mistyped the function call for your errors for `group_indices`, perhaps passing `"description"` instead of `description`?

Comment: This code runs and the sample output looks correct, but then when I try to View(df) the index column is not visible. When I try to call df$index the result is NULL. Do you know why this is?

Comment: The following code works and includes the question when I type View(df): df$index <- as.integer(factor(df$description, levels = unique(df$description)))

Comment: Because i didn't include the assignment step in the line so that the output would print in the example... if you did `df <- df %>% mutate(...)` it would overwrite `df`

Answer (score 0):

R base solution

```
> df$question <- as.numeric(df$description)
> df
  block description question
1     1      enroll        1
2     1      enroll        1
3     1   motivated        2
4     1   motivated        2
5     1   motivated        2
6     2   openemail        3
7     2   openemail        3
```

Comment: This creates a separate column for question but does not populate the column.